# how to exclude some calls with the Feign from tracing with the cloud sleuth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

there's a microservice **with spring-boot 1.5** which uses the ***Feign*** to communicate with others services, also there's ***spring-cloud-starter-zipkin*** which wrapped all calls through the Feign and sends tracing to zipkin server.
The thing is i don't wanna wrap all calls and trace them, there're only several most important to do that.
How can i exclude some calls(methods) with Feign from tracing or exlude some whole Feign client(interface)?

Answer (score 1):

In Sleuth `1.3.x` you can create a custom `SpanReporter` that, before sending a span to Zipkin, would analyze the URL and would not report that span. In Sleuth `2.0.x` you can create a custom `HttpSampler` for the client side (with name `sleuthClientSampler`)